# In Drools, how to find the keyword with the least number of matches?

Tags: drools, rule-engine

I have some tokenized string like this

```
declare UserAddress
    tokens : List
end
```

and I have a list of recognized tokens like this

```
rule "Count Frequency of RealTokens occurrence in RealAddresses"
salience -10
when
    $token : RealToken();
    $count : List() from collect(RealAddress(tokens contains $token.getToken()));   
then
    modify($token) { setCount($count) };
end
```

Using drools, how can I determine, which of the `tokens` in a given `UserAddress` matches the `RealToken` with the lowest possible `$count` value?

I already tried this:

```
rule "Find the Most Statistically Significant Token for each User Address"
salience -20
    $ua : UserAddress();
    $ut : String( length() > 0) from $ua.getTokens().subList(1, $ua.getTokens().size());
    $rt : RealToken(token == $ut);
    not(RealToken(token == $ut && this.count < $rt.count));
then
    System.out.println("MSST: " + $ua.toString() + " = " + $rt.toString());
end
```

But couldn't get past the DRL syntax issue:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Found errors in package builder
[85,1]: [ERR 102] Line 85:1 mismatched input '$ua' in rule "Find the Most Statistically Significant Token for each User Address"
[0,0]: Parser returned a null Package
```

Comment: According to rule "Count Frequency..." field `count` in `RealToken` is a List - this can't be compared using `<`. Also, why is the first List element excluded in the second rule (`subList(1,...`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is quite clear, and when you would have bothered to look at line 85, you would have found that

```
rule "Find the Most Statistically Significant Token for each User Address"
salience -20
    $ua : UserAddress();  ############################### line 85
    $ut : String( length() > 0) from $ua.getTokens().subList(1, $ua.getTokens().size());
    $rt : RealToken(token == $ut);
```

there is no keyword `when` preceding the first pattern.

Comment: Thanks. I stared at that line a few times and didn't see anything wrong with it.